# Preapre output of console for compdef

Tags: awk, sed, zsh

I've got a list of commands like this:

```sh
  cleanup                   Cleaning up old releases
  deploy                    Deploy your project
 domain
  domain:dns                Output the IP addresses for the host
  domain:force              Configure the server to force a specific domain
  domain:ssl                Add Let's Encrypt SSL certificate
  domain:ssl:request        Requested the SSl certificate
```

The list is an output from a command, the spaces are blanks.

The goal is to create an array for `compdef`:

```sh
cmdlist=("cleanup:Cleaning up old releases" "deploy:Deploy your project" "domain\:dns:Output the IP addresses for the host" "domain\:force:Configure the server to force a specific domain" "domain\:ssl:Add Let's Encrypt SSL certificate" "domain\:ssl\:request:Requested the SSl certificate")
```

The `:` is used as a separator in compdef, if there is one in the command or description, it should be escaped

It is important, that only the commands get in the array. I was able to create a plain list with `awk '/^(  )/ { print $0}'`:

```
  cleanup                   Cleaning up old releases
  deploy                    Deploy your project
  domain:dns                Output the IP addresses for the host
  domain:force              Configure the server to force a specific domain
  domain:ssl                Add Let's Encrypt SSL certificate
  domain:ssl:request        Requested the SSl certificate
```

How can I achieve to create the array?

Comment: Why in `"domain:dns:Output...` is the first `:`s not escaped but in `"domain\:force:Configure...` and `domain\:ssl:Add...` it is? What should happen if the text in the right input column contained `:`s? Is your "list of commands" stored in a file or coming from a pipe or the output of a command or something else? Are the spaces between columns in the input tabs or blanks or something else?

Comment: Sorry, you're right. There is one command too much in the cmdlist. The output should be: `cmdlist=("cleanup:Cleaning up old releases" "deploy:Deploy your project" "domain\:dns:Output the IP addresses for the host" "domain\:force:Configure the server to force a specific domain" "domain\:ssl:Add Let's Encrypt SSL certificate" "domain\:ssl\:request:Requested the SSl certificate"` The list is an output from an command, the spaces are blanks. The `:` is used as a seperator in `compdef`, if there is one in the command or description, it should be escaped.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to fix any issues and provide any additional information, don't spread it out between your question and comments.